# Json Object Deserialization in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

im tyring to deserialize my object coming from client side having following format:

```
{'goalplans':
   [{"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0},
    {"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0},
    {"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0},
    {"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0},
    {"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0},
    {"goalPlan":0,"accountId":11,"objectiveId":17,"activity":35,"acctOwner":0,"planDay":"1/30/2013","spend_budget":12,"sortBy":0,"activityFlag":0}
]}
```

thing is that im not able to deserialze it on my server side .

Please tell me  how can i deserialize the Json object to a list object like 
List . i tried many ways but not working.

Answer (score 4):

serialize/deserialize objects to/from JSON exist Since .NET 3.5, try this

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonText);
```

See [here](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c/) for more details

Hope this helps

Comment: Looks to me like it should be a Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string, string>>> (Or possibly the last string should be int, I can't remember if the JavaScriptSerializer will do ints.)

Comment: Edited,  it was just for sample @Rawling, in this case we don't need dictionary at all

Comment: Mapping the JSON structure to some form of object model definitely makes life easier.

Comment: The standard serializers of the .NET framework aren't nearly as powerful as JSON.NET.

Answer (score 2):

One possible third party component is JSON.NET. Personally I have made very good experience with that library ( it is available using nuget for example )

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself. Simply adding `[Serializable]` to my class
and changed method to take argument of class type ...
e.g.

```
//My class
[Serializable]
public class GoalPlanList{}

//method
public static int GoalplanAddUPD(List<GoalPlanList> goalplans)
{
    foreach (GoalPlanList goals in goalplans)
    {}
}
```